# Google verification challenge with file location

Tags: images, site-url, google-analytics

Our team lost access to our Google Analytics account and the only way we can get it back is by inserting a text file into our website. However, the link for uploading files is something like `www.whatever.com/uploads/media/2017-analytics`.

I tried just sending them the media file link so that they can view it directly and see that it is from our domain, but they said that is not acceptable.

Google just wants to view the file itself at `www.whatever.com/analytics`. They will not budge and I can't figure out how to change the media URL to what Google wants it to be.

Answer (score 4):

Google wants to see that you have ownership of the domain, because on some sites, subscribers have the ability to upload to the media library. You'll need to upload the file using FTP/SFTP to the domain's root folder (i.e. public_html or www). You should be able to get these from your hosting provider. Sometimes they can also upload the file for you.